# Shopware 6 Docker Setup add PHPMyAdmin

Tags: docker, phpmyadmin, e-commerce, shopware, shopware6

I am a totally beginner at Shopware and I want to use PhpMyAdmin for my local Shopware 6 setup.

For the download I used the official Shopware 6 Development repository https://github.com/shopware/development

I've already seen that the docker-compose.yml has implemented the following:

```
app_mysql:
    build: dev-ops/docker/containers/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_USER: app
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: app
    networks:
      shopware:
        aliases:
          - mysql
```

and now I want to implement phpmyadmin. I tried the following:

```
phpmyadmin:
      image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
      links:
          - app_mysql:mysql
      depends_on:
          - app_mysql
      ports:
          - 8181:80
      environment:
          PMA_HOST: app_mysql
          MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
          MYSQL_USER: app
          MYSQL_PASSWORD: app
```

phpmyadmin is visible on localhost:8181 but when I try to login I get the following errors:

**mysqli::real_connect(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known
mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2002): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known**

How can I solve it?

Comment: For local setup you could also use Dockware (dockware.io). Dockware comes with a complete docker setup for development and has adminer per default (/adminer.php)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Usually `phpmyadmin` should be in the same network as the database.
Service names are resolved to the IP addresses of the containers, therefore it's recommended to use names allowed by [RFC1035](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1035) to avoid additional problems.

I removed `links:`, `aliases`, `depends_on` that are deprecated/not required and ended up with this `docker-compose.yml`.

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  app-mysql:
    #build: dev-ops/docker/containers/mysql
    image: mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_USER: app
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: app
    networks:
      - shopware
  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    ports:
        - 8181:80
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: app-mysql
      PMA_PORT: 3306
      PMA_ARBITRARY: 1
    networks:
      - shopware
networks:
  shopware
```

Run the containers:

```
docker-compose up
```

Open `http://localhost:8181/index.php` in a browser.
Use

```
Server:    app-mysql
Username:  root
Password:  root
```

Enjoy:

[image]

Comment: I did but at least I have less than 15 rep and that's why it is not shown public :D

Answer (score 0):

You must use as host mysql or app_mysql

Comment: I used in the environment section app_mysql for PMA_HOST.
What do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

It is not an answer, but try
http://localhost:8001/
it is not phpMyAdmin but it is another tool `Adminer` :)

Answer (score 0):

You should link phpmyadmin and mysql using

```
links:
      - app_mysql:mysql
```

use it as :

```
links:
      - mysql
```

Add environment:

```
`PMA_HOST`: mysql
```

Comment: Thanks but why should I use mysql as linking instead of app_mysql:mysql when the sql service is named app_mysql?

That causes an undefined service linking when I restart the project :/